# Doing a selective rebase

Tags: git, github

I have a branch called "test" based off of master. I have made 2 commits on test and master has had 4 commits made to it since I last git rebased off of master. Now say the commits are as follows (latest at the top)

```
*master*
commit d
commit c
commit b
commit a
```

My test branch looks like this:

```
*test*
commit 2
commit 1
```

Now i only want to rebase the first three commits and not all 4. So i would want only commits a-c to be rebased onto my test branch. How can i do this? It should look like this in the end:

```
*test*
commit 2
commit 1
commit c
commit b
commit a
```

Comment: I don't have time to work through an example, but I have done this before by applying `git cherrypick`.

Comment: Which commit is the most recent common ancestor of the two branch tips?

Comment: Just `git cherry-pick a b c`, no?

Comment: @jthill The way I understand the question, the arrow of time points upwards: commits at the top of each list are the most recent ones on the branch.

Comment: @jubobs Oops, missed the reordering, right.

Comment: `git rebase --onto c master test`

Comment: jthill: Post your rebase as an answer.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you simply want to rebase your test branch on the commit `c`: `git rebase shaofcommitc`

Comment: @jthill your command worked perfectly!

Comment: @JBNizet that's true and much better if he's got the `test` branch checked out atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's easy:

```
git rebase --onto c master test
```

Git command parameters tend to be chosen to permit concise command lines in the common cases, that leads to this hard-to-appreciate one here :-)